# NaN problems with cuFFT

Tags: c++, cuda, fft, cufft

I'm writing a frequency filtering application for a school assignment in C++ and Cuda using cuFFT and I can't get it to work. You can find the whole Visual Studio 2010 solution [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17798054/Fourier_en.zip). (Needs [glut](http://user.xmission.com/~nate/glut.html).)

Here is the part I think is relevant: (fourierUtils.cu/194)

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Function to help invoking the kernel, creates the parameters and gets 
// the result
__host__
void Process(
        BitmapStruct& in_img, // these contain an image in an rgba byte array
        BitmapStruct& out_img, 
        MaskGenerator maskGenerator, // this is a pointer to a device function
        float param1, // mask parameters
        float param2)
{    
    // Declare and allocate variables
    cufftHandle plan;

    cufftReal* img;
    cufftReal* dev_img;
    cufftComplex* dev_freq_img;

    int imgsize = in_img.image_size();
    int pixelcount = imgsize / 4;

    img = new float[pixelcount];
    checkResult(
        cudaMalloc(&dev_img, sizeof(cufftReal) * pixelcount));
    checkResult(
        cudaMalloc(&dev_freq_img, sizeof(cufftComplex) * pixelcount));

    // Optimize execution
    cudaFuncAttributes attrs;
    checkResult(
        cudaFuncGetAttributes(&attrs, &Filter));
    std::pair<dim3, dim3> params 
        = Optimizer::GetOptimalParameters(pixelcount, attrs);

    // Process r, g, b channels
    for(int chan = 0; chan <= 2; chan++)
    {
        // Init
        for(int i = 0; i < pixelcount; i++)
        {
            img[i] = in_img.pixels[4 * i + chan];
        }

        checkResult(
            cudaMemcpy(dev_img, img, pixelcount, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

        // Create frequency image
        checkResult(
            cufftPlan1d(&plan, pixelcount, CUFFT_R2C, 1));
        checkResult(
            cufftExecR2C(plan, dev_img, dev_freq_img));
        checkResult(
            cudaThreadSynchronize());
        checkResult(
            cufftDestroy(plan));

        // Mask frequency image
        Filter<<<params.first, params.second>>>(
            dev_freq_img, in_img.x, in_img.y, maskGenerator, param1, param2);
        getLastCudaError("Filtering the image failed.");

        // Get result
        checkResult(
            cufftPlan1d(&plan, pixelcount, CUFFT_C2R, 1));
        checkResult(
            cufftExecC2R(plan, dev_freq_img, dev_img));
        checkResult(
            cudaThreadSynchronize());
        checkResult(
            cufftDestroy(plan));
        checkResult(
            cudaMemcpy(img, dev_img, pixelcount, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

        for(int i = 0; i < pixelcount; i++)
        {
            out_img.pixels[4 * i + chan] = img[i];
        }
    }

    // Copy alpha channel
    for(int i = 0; i < pixelcount; i++)
    {
        out_img.pixels[4 * i + 3] = in_img.pixels[4 * i + 3];
    }

    // Free memory
    checkResult(
        cudaFree(dev_freq_img));
    checkResult(
        cudaFree(dev_img));
    delete img;

    getLastCudaError("An error occured during processing the image.");
}
```

I can't see any practical differences compared to the official examples I've seen, yet when I debug into it with Nsight, all the cufftComplex values received by my kernel are NaNs and the only difference between the [input](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17798054/teszter.bmp) and the [result](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17798054/il_01.bmp) images are that the result has a black bar at the bottom, no matter which filtering mask and what parameters I use. All Cuda and cuFFT calls return success and there is no error reported after the kernel invocation either.

What do I do wrong?

I've tried replacing img and dev_img with complex arrays and using C2C conversions and also doing them inplace, but it only changed the size of the black bar on the result image.

Thank you for your help.

**Edit:** [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17798054/Fouriermin.zip) is a reduced version that doesn't need glut and should also compile on linux.

Comment: If you omit the filtering step do you get your original image back or do you still get `NaN`s ?

Comment: I think it will be somewhat time consuming for people to deal with you whole VS psoject including glut, especially for linux users. Could you please provide a more concise example reproducing your problem?

Comment: @PaulR well I get the NaNs IN the filtering step, but omitting it does not change the end result (the filter tries to multiply the nans, which does nothing to them).  
I might be wrong, but it seems to me, that my kernel cannot access the memory pointed by dev_freq_img (which is weird as it is in the device memory). And the black bar appearing could be a different problem.

Comment: @JackOLantern I'll try to make a reduced version then, but the bmp I/O seems to depend on glut, so I'm not sure I can make a decent version without it.

Comment: I made a reduced version: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17798054/Fouriermin.zip)  
  
It should work on linux as well, although I don't have the resources to test it. It also doesn't need glut. I left it in a Visual Studio solution, but you can just compile the sources with nvcc and gcc I think. I wanted to make a makefile, but unfortunately I'm not too familiar with them so I didn't, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was forgetting to multiply the number of items with their size in some of the `cudaMemcpy` calls, thus the end of the vectors fed to cuFFT was made up of NaNs. Fixing those has solved the problem.

I also replaced the cufftReal arrays with cufftComplex ones as the C2C transformations seem to be more predictable and added normalization for the values.

So the final working method is:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Function to help invoking the kernel, creates the parameters and gets 
// the result
__host__
void Process(
        BitmapStruct& in_img, 
        BitmapStruct& out_img, 
        MaskGenerator maskGenerator, 
        float param1, 
        float param2)
{    
    // Declare and allocate variables
    cufftHandle plan;

    cufftComplex* img;
    cufftComplex* dev_img;
    cufftComplex* dev_freq_img;

    int imgsize = in_img.image_size();
    int pixelcount = imgsize / 4;

    img = new cufftComplex[pixelcount];
    checkResult(
        cudaMalloc(&dev_img, sizeof(cufftComplex) * pixelcount));
    checkResult(
        cudaMalloc(&dev_freq_img, sizeof(cufftComplex) * pixelcount));

    // Optimize execution
    cudaFuncAttributes attrs;
    checkResult(
        cudaFuncGetAttributes(&attrs, &Filter));
    std::pair<dim3, dim3> params = 
            Optimizer::GetOptimalParameters(pixelcount, attrs);

    // Process r, g, b channels
    for(int chan = 0; chan <= 2; chan++)
    {
        // Init
        for(int i = 0; i < pixelcount; i++)
        {
            img[i].x = in_img.pixels[4 * i + chan];
            img[i].y = 0;
        }

        checkResult(
            cudaMemcpy(
                dev_img, 
                img, 
                pixelcount * sizeof(cufftComplex), 
                cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

        // Create frequency image
        checkResult(
            cufftPlan1d(&plan, pixelcount, CUFFT_C2C, 1));
        checkResult(
            cufftExecC2C(plan, dev_img, dev_freq_img, CUFFT_FORWARD));
        checkResult(
            cudaThreadSynchronize());
        checkResult(
            cufftDestroy(plan));

        // Mask frequency image
        Filter<<<params.first, params.second>>>(
            dev_freq_img, 
            in_img.x, 
            in_img.y, 
            maskGenerator, 
            param1, 
            param2);
        getLastCudaError("Filtering the image failed.");

        // Get result
        checkResult(
            cufftPlan1d(&plan, pixelcount, CUFFT_C2C, 1));
        checkResult(
            cufftExecC2C(plan, dev_freq_img, dev_img, CUFFT_INVERSE));
        checkResult(
            cudaThreadSynchronize());
        checkResult(
            cufftDestroy(plan));
        checkResult(
            cudaMemcpy(
                img, 
                dev_img, 
                pixelcount * sizeof(cufftComplex), 
                cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

        for(int i = 0; i < pixelcount; i++)
        {
            out_img.pixels[4 * i + chan] = img[i].x / pixelcount;
        }
    }

    // Copy alpha channel
    for(int i = 0; i < pixelcount; i++)
    {
        out_img.pixels[4 * i + 3] = in_img.pixels[4 * i + 3];
    }

    // Free memory
    checkResult(
        cudaFree(dev_freq_img));
    checkResult(
        cudaFree(dev_img));
    delete img;

    getLastCudaError("An error occured during processing the image.");
}
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't compiled and run your reduced version, but I think the problem is in the size of `dev_img` and `dev_freq_imag`.

Consider the example on Section 4.2 of the CUFFT Library User's Guide. It performs an in-place real-to-complex transform, which is the same step you are performing first.

```
#define NX 256

cufftHandle plan;
cufftComplex *data;
cudaMalloc((void**)&data, sizeof(cufftComplex)*(NX/2+1)*BATCH);

cufftPlan1d(&plan, NX, CUFFT_R2C, BATCH);
cufftExecR2C(plan, (cufftReal*)data, data);
```

Due to the symmetry properties of the transform, `cufftExecR2C` fills only `NX/2+1` output elements, where `NX` is the size of the input array.

In your case, you are doing the following:

```
cufftHandle plan;

cufftReal* dev_img;
cufftComplex* dev_freq_img;

cudaMalloc(&dev_img, sizeof(cufftReal) * pixelcount);
cudaMalloc(&dev_freq_img, sizeof(cufftComplex) * pixelcount);
```

so you are allocating a `cufftReal` array and a `cufftComplex` array of the same size. When you use

```
cufftPlan1d(&plan, pixelcount, CUFFT_R2C, 1);
cufftExecR2C(plan, dev_img, dev_freq_img);
```

then only half of the `dev_freq_img` is filled by `cufftExecR2C`, the remaining part containing garbage. If you use the full extent of `dev_freq_img` in the `Filter` `__global__` function, then this will be probably the cause of your `NaN`s.

Comment: I rewrote it like this: `cudaMalloc(&dev_freq_img, sizeof(cufftComplex) * freqImgSize)` where `int freqImgSize = pixelcount / 2 + 1;` and start this many instances of my kernel, but unfortunately it didn't change anything. The entire array is NaNs and the result image has a black bar at the bottom and is otherwise unchanged.

Comment: Could you use `cuda-memcheck` to see if you are violating memory bounds? Have you identified which is the routine generating the `NaN`s?

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. I don't know, I'll try dumping it after each call.

Comment: While tracing the arrays I have found my mistake, it was as stupid as I thought it was going to be: I forgot to multiply the number of elements with their size in some of the `cudaMemcpy`s, thus the last 3/4 of the vectors fed to cuFFT was NaNs resulting the entire frequency vector to be made up of NaNs... So after fixing that it works now, thank you for your help.